# HDMI Audio not working on Ubuntu 22.04 depending on the resolution

Tags: sound, 22.04, hdmi

Have freshly installed 22.04 and the sound through HDMI it's not working.
What I noticed is that it works on 3840x2160, if I change to any other resolution, it stops working.

Comment: @Nmath Before, I had ubuntu 20.04 and it was working with other resolutions. Sometimes it would break, but would work after reboot.

Comment: @Nmath Problem is on 4k when I watch a movie the image twitches, that's why I want another resolution, not the size of the interface is the problem. Thing is on Windows all worked well, so if Windows can, Linux should too.

Answer (score 0):

After I

1. installed the old nvidia-driver-470 driver
2. pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload

everything worked. I don't know if point 2 is needed